# Can these two LINQ-to-SQL queries be combined?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have two tables, `Exam` and `ExamGroup` which have a *:* relationship. I am given a `List<Exam>` and need to determine if an `ExamGroup` for this list already exists. So the provided list might be A+B+C, `ExamGroups` will contain, A+B, A+C, A+B+C+D+E, etc. and I need to determine if A+B+C exists and create it if it doesn't. The code below seems to do it but I'm wondering if it's possible to do it in a single expression?

```cs
var givenExams = /* Provided list of exams */
var examGroup = _context
    .ExamGroups
    .Include(x => x.ExamGroupsExam) // Mapping table for EF Core
    .ThenInclude(y => y.Exam)
    .AsEnumerable();

examGroup = givenExams.Aggregate(
    examGroup, 
    (current, exam) => current.Where(x => x.Exams.Contains(exam)));
```

At this point `examGroup` is either the relevant group (which has an ID and other fields I care about) or null, at which point I know to create it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. You need to use only the `ExamGroupsExam` table to determine it. Please filter down the `ExamGroupsExam` table by `ExamId` (using `givenExams` list) inside a sub query and then group the `ExamId` by the `ExamGroupId`. From this point, the query can identify the number of exams in that group. If this number is matching with the number of items in the `givenExams` then the group is exists if not you can create it. :)

I did create a query from top of my head, hopefully it will help you move forward:

```
var examGroupExists = (from examGroupsExam in _context.ExamGroupsExam
                     where (from examGroupsExam in _context.ExamGroupsExam
                            where givenExams.Any(x => x.Id == examGroupsExam.ExamId)
                            select examGroupsExam.ExamGroupId).Any(x == examGroupsExam.ExamGroupId)
                     group examGroupsExam.ExamId by examGroupsExam.ExamGroupId
                     into examGroup
                     select new {
                        NumberOfExamsInGroup = examGroup.Count(),
                        ExamGroupId = examGroup.Key
                     }).Any(x => x.NumberOfExamsInGroup == givenExams.Count);
                 
if (examGroupExists == false) 
{
    // then create it
}
```

EDIT: I've noticed there was a bug in the first query, so I've changed it above and added a subquery. Basically the bug was: if A + B + C + D exam was one group then if you were looking for A + B + C group is returned true, with the sub select this should work okay.